Can someone help me install this Global Entry Slot Notifier tool for Ubuntu?
I would like to install this on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS via terminal. I am sure many of you could do this in your sleep, but I don't know what the steps would be.
Here are the links:
https://github.com/arun0009/global-entry-slot-notifier?tab=readme-ov-file
and
https://github.com/arun0009/global-entry-appointment

Please one question at a time. I answered for the first question global-entry-slot-notifier.

Install git and build essential and go:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git make build-essential golang-go

Clone the repository:
cd
git clone https://github.com/arun0009/global-entry-slot-notifier
cd global-entry-slot-notifier

then do as the instructions say:
make all

This will build the stuff you can execute in the current directory.
So it shows the usage as ./global-entry-slot-notifier and if you're not in the directory, then the usage would be ~/global-entry-slot-notifier/global-entry-slot-notifier to run the command.
